# #define across a whole program

Tags: c++, preprocessor-directive

Is it possible (and if so is it a good idea) to have a preprocessor directive, particularly #define to apply across a whole application, or at least multiple files?

I'm trying to manipulate an array in multiple parts of a program, so I have to make sure the memory allocated to it is still in scope.

To do this I've decided I want to declare the array inside my main object, which wont be deleted until the app is quit. The problem is I don't know at compile time how large my array needs to be, so I want to use `#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 20`.

This is fine, but I'd like to only need to change the max size in one place. Is there a good (and safe) way to do this or should I suck it up and put the #define in all the files that need it?

Comment: Why not use a global `std::vector` which can change size as needed?

Comment: I don't need to dynamically change the size of the array after it is created, and I understand that `std::vector` is very expensive memory and operation wise compared to arrays

Comment: Nope. It does have a cost to create but you create it only once. You can't notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fine to have a #define across multiple files.  You could do this with a header file that is shared.  However, it doesn't sound like that will solve your problem.

If you don't know the size of your array at compile time, this will not help--since #define will only work at compile time.

You could simply have the size of the array as another variable and dynamically allocate your array using new and delete it using delete[].  Or simply use std:vector.

Comment: My thinking was that including a max array size bigger than I would *probably* need would alleviate my problem, and allow me to easily change one #define if it turned out in the future that I needed more space than I thought.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could dynamically create arrays like that, any chance you could explain further, or point me to a good explanation?

Answer (score 3):

If you use gcc/g++ or compatible tools you can add it as a compiler directive, for example in your makefile.

```
g++ ... -DMAX_ARRAY_SIZE=20 ...
```

This is a common way to #define across the whole build and it makes the change very isolated, which is nice.

Comment: It's a nice and clean approach to move the problem to the build environment. It should be possible for any decent compiler, not just gcc/g++.

Answer (score 2):

create a global header-file and use [header-guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). After inclusion of this global header in each of your headerfiles / *.c / *.cpp - files you will have the macro available to your local code. I would include the global header in your implementation-files IF you dont want to use the macro in your headers ... which is what i also recommend.

example :

global.h:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#define GLOBAL_H
#define MYCONSTANT 0xFF
#endif
```

child-files:

```
#ifndef GLOBAL_H
#include "global.h"
#endif
```

also dont forget to use

```
#pragma once
```

[if your compiler supports it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once)

Comment: Why would you guard the include in the "child-files" if `global.h` already has an include guard?

Comment: two are better than one - these compiler-statements are rather inexpensive AND are automatically reduced/removed/optimized from the compiler, they also dont affect runtime-performance so one can use them without thinking twice.

Comment: I've accepted another answer as it's a better solution for my problem, but I think this is the best answer to my actual question. I have upvoted both.

Should I change my accepted answer to this?

Comment: i think the general consensus is : "accept the answer which actually solved your problem / answered your question". I think it comes down to "which one was the most useful answer?"

Comment: @pmr: The double-guard thing was popular about ten years ago. It was recommended in, for example, _Large-Scale C++ Software Design_ and genuinely improved compile times back then. More modern compilers are often able to handle this better anyway, and the general consensus is that the additional noise and error risk of the double guards is not worth it.

Comment: "additional error risk" doesnt make any sense at all. You clearly dont know how preprocessor-statements (especially this one) work.

Comment: i'd like to add something not so obvious for beginners : header-guards are timeless, there was never "a time" in which they "were popular" - its good practise AND will avoid the most annoying mistakes. Your compiler cant possibly remove your personal mistakes - files can quite easily be included two times without you being able to know it, some of these inclusions produce very weird errors which are traceable only if you posess in-depth knowledge about your compiler and build-system. Always remember to avoid double inclusions, it WILL save you a few headaches.

Comment: I believe JackAidley was referring to using `#pragma once` on its own instead of using *both* the pragma *and* the include guards. His comment is perfectly reasonable and correct.

Comment: *"additional error risk"* still doesn not make any sense whatsoever, the **prevention of double-inclusion** cannot be erroneous under any circumstance, thats logically impossible - in the worst case it increases the  time needed to compile

Comment: @specializt I interpret that phrase to mean the risk of an error on the programmer's part; *any* additional line of code is an additional risk. For instance, you could forget the `#endif`. Also, it's not "logically impossible" for there to be a use-case for double-inclusion; for instance, you could include a file twice using different definitions of a particular macro each time.

Comment: basically, you try to disprove my words and agree to them at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is often handled by the build toolchain, rather than in the code.  It's surprisingly difficult to apply a `#define` to a whole program, especially when that program is large.

If you're using cmake to create the makefiles, you can do `cmake ... -DMAX_ARRAY_SIZE=20`.  Under linux using gcc, this ultimately ends up becoming `g++ ... -DMAX_ARRAY_SIZE=20`, which you can also do if your building from hand rather than using makefiles.

On another note, this is not a great use for macros IMO.  Macros skirt around the C++ type system, are very difficult to debug & maintain, and should usually be avoided unless you have no other choice.  There are times when you have no other choice -- but this isn't one of them.  instead of a macro, use a real variable:

```
static const size_t MaxArraySize = 20;
```

This should be in a header included everywhere you want to use it.  There will be only one place where this declaration exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yep! declare it as a MACRO or just as a gobal variable in a header file.
Make sure to include this header file where you use/ modify.

if you are also looking to modify it then global variable is simplest way to handle it.
It is also possible to be done using MACRO

just use:

undef MAX_ARRAY_SIZE

define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE 100

Comment: Defining global variable in a header will lead to multiple definition error during compilation

Comment: I dont see any error. On using undef it always get undefined and then re-defining will not cause any issue.

Comment: #undef is relevant to compile-time constructs only. It has no effect on global variables.

Answer (score -1):

You have several options here. Classic approach is to to move your `#define` to a header file and include it from any relevant source file.

A better approach might be this:

```
template <class T, int maxSize = 20>
class myClass
{
    T myArr[maxSize];
    ...
};

int main()
{
    myClass<int> x;
    return 0;
}
```

This way there is no need for all the logistics of the macro approach.

Comment: he wants to have the SIZE-CONSTANT globally available, not the actual member

Comment: @specializt He wants to have an array of constant size to persist throughout the entire program lifetime

Comment: no.
   "I'd like to only need to change the max size in one place."

Comment: @specializt That's exactly what my solution provides - maxSize is defined in one place only.